# RPT receiver: are answers necessary?

Tags: video-streaming, rtp

Assume I have a camera which streams RTP/H.264 to a media server. Question is, is RTP responses (as defined by [RFC 3550, 6.4.2 RR: Receiver Report RTCP Packet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550#section-6.4.2)) mandatory? That is, will it be okay if I just ignore all the responses?

To add a context: I'm adjusting a proxy server that relays an RTP stream, but does not relay anything back. Question is, should I care, and if yes, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its depends on your camera.
Some cameras need you to send back "keepalive" messages.
if those messages are not arriving to the camera than it will stop sending rtp packets.
if you have your own way to "talk" with the camera (like the camera webpage) it will not stop streaming and you don't need those response.